# SQL operator "Left Join" works differently

Tags: sql

I have 2 DBs and I want to create a new DB which will contain lines from the first and these lines are not present in the second. In other words, to find a regression in data from the first DB to the second. 
When I use operator "Left Join" with DBs which contain numbers, then I get expected results. But when I use the same operator with 2 DBs with URLs then I get too much of lines as a result. 
What is the difference between words and digits for this operator?

Comment: none, the difference is with your query or data

Comment: You can't join two "DBs" - you can only join tables.

Comment: please look here to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data from a table in database 1 into a `DataTable` (call it table1) and the "similar" data (ie from the matching table) in database 2 into another `DataTable` (call it table2).

From there, you can invoke the table1.AsEnumerable().Except() method.

See answers to these questions:
[How to compare 2 dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517968/how-to-compare-2-datatables) or [How to get difference between two DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002623/how-to-get-difference-between-two-datatables)