# How to find the differences between two datatables

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

How to get the differences between two datatables?

Looking at this: [How to compare 2 dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517968/how-to-compare-2-datatables)

I tried this:

```
DataTable dataTable1; // Load with data
DataTable dataTable2; // Load with data (same schema)

var differences =
    dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Except(dataTable2.AsEnumerable(),
                                        DataRowComparer.Default);

return differences.Any() ? differences.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();
```

but got  this:

```
"Public member 'Any' on type '<ExceptIterator>d__73(Of DataRow)' not found."
```

Looking at this: [How to get difference between two DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002623/how-to-get-difference-between-two-datatables)

I tried this:

```
DataSet firstDsData = new DataSet();
DataSet secondDsData = new DataSet();
DataSet finalDsData = new DataSet();
DataSet DifferenceDataSet = new DataSet();
finalDsData.Merge(firstDsData);
finalDsData.AcceptChanges();
finalDsData.Merge(secondDsData);
DifferenceDataSet = finalDsData.GetChanges();
```

But get this:

```
?DifferenceDataSet
Nothing
```

I know there is a difference because I put it there.

I do not wish to link tables because the app allows any server and any database to be compared.  This is so we can easily view the data from production, test and development as the need arises.

Also note that the data table is built using "SELECT *" but will eventually be able to be changed to choose certain fields.

Yeah, I could loop through the rows and columns, but this would require a sort.  And since any table could be used I would have to pull the PK data from SQL server, append it to the sql.  While not impossible, I hope there is a better way.

I do not wish to use LINQ, but do not stop from posting LINQ solutions since they may help others.

My code:

```
Public Function GetTable(ByVal strTable As String, ByVal strServer As String, ByVal strDatabase As String, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPassword As String) As DataTable

    Dim DT As DataTable


    Using Conn As New SqlConnection

        Conn.ConnectionString = [String].Format(mconSQLConnectString, strServer, strDatabase, strUser, strPassword, strDatabase)
        Conn.Open()

        DT = New DataTable

        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & strTable, Conn)
            DT.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
            DT.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        End Using

    End Using

    Return DT

End Function



Private Sub Diff()

    Dim DT As DataTable
    Dim DTS As DataTable
    Dim DTT As DataTable
    Dim strTableName As String
    Dim TableNode As TreeNode


    mdictSource = New Dictionary(Of String, DataTable)
    mdictTarget = New Dictionary(Of String, DataTable)

    For Each TableNode In treSource.Nodes

        strTableName = TableNode.Text

        If TableNode.Checked Then
            DTS = DA.GetTable(strTableName, cboServerSource.Text, cboDatabaseSource.Text, txtUserSource.Text, txtPasswordSource.Text)
            mdictSource.Add(strTableName, DT)
            DTT = DA.GetTable(strTableName, cboServerTarget.Text, cboDatabaseTarget.Text, txtUserTarget.Text, txtPasswordTarget.Text)
            mdictTarget.Add(strTableName, DT)

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'Method 1
            Dim differences
            differences = DTS.AsEnumerable().Except(DTT.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)

            If differences.Any() Then 'Public member 'Any' on type '<ExceptIterator>d__73(Of DataRow)' not found.
                DT = differences.CopyToDataTable
            End If
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'Method 2
            Dim finalDsData = New DataSet
            Dim DifferenceDataSet As DataSet
            finalDsData.Merge(DTS)
            finalDsData.AcceptChanges()
            finalDsData.Merge(DTT)
            DifferenceDataSet = finalDsData.GetChanges()

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I know there is a difference because I created it:

```
?DTt.rows(11).Item(2)
"RFQs Issued" {String}
    String: "RFQs Issued"
?DTs.rows(11).Item(2)
"RFQs Issued!" {String}
    String: "RFQs Issued!"
```

I don't really care how I get the results as long as I get the table, pkey and field(s)

EDIT: Solution to finding mis-matching primary keys.  Still need to check datatypes but when this logic is complete it should be easy to include non-primary key columns:

```
Private Sub Diff()

    Dim DGV As DataGridView
    Dim DT As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim DTS As DataTable
    Dim DTT As DataTable
    Dim strMessage As String
    Dim TP As TabPage
    Dim strTableName As String
    Dim TableNode As TreeNode


    mdictSource = New Dictionary(Of String, DataTable)
    mdictTarget = New Dictionary(Of String, DataTable)

    For Each TableNode In treSource.Nodes

        If TableNode.Checked Then

            strTableName = TableNode.Text
            DGV = New DataGridView
            DGV.AllowUserToAddRows = False
            DGV.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            DGV.Name = "dgv" & strTableName
            DGV.Visible = True
            TP = New TabPage
            TP.Name = "tp" & strTableName
            TP.Text = strTableName
            TP.Controls.Add(DGV)
            tcTableResults.TabPages.Add(TP)

            DTS = DA.GetTable(strTableName, cboServerSource.Text, cboDatabaseSource.Text, txtUserSource.Text, txtPasswordSource.Text)
            mdictSource.Add(strTableName, DT)
            DTT = DA.GetTable(strTableName, cboServerTarget.Text, cboDatabaseTarget.Text, txtUserTarget.Text, txtPasswordTarget.Text)
            mdictTarget.Add(strTableName, DT)

            If PrimarykeyCountMatches(DTS, DTT) Then

                If PrimarykeysMatch(DGV, DTS, DTT) Then

                    If ColumnCountMatches(DTS, DTT) Then

                        If ColumnsMatch(DTS, DTT) Then

                            strMessage &= strTableName & " matches." & Environment.NewLine

                        Else

                        End If

                    Else

                        DisplayDiffPrimarykeys(DGV, DTS, DTT)

                    End If

                End If

            Else

                DisplayDiffPrimarykeys(DGV, DTS, DTT)

            End If

        End If

    Next

    If strMessage <> String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show(strMessage, "Results")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DisplayDiffColumns(DGV As DataGridView, DTS As DataTable, DTT As DataTable)



End Sub

Private Sub DisplayDiffPrimarykeys(DGV As DataGridView, DTS As DataTable, DTT As DataTable)

    Dim DC As DataGridViewColumn
    Dim DR As DataGridViewRow
    Dim intNewRow As Integer
    Dim intOffset As Integer
    Dim r As Integer

    For r = 0 To DTS.PrimaryKey.Length - 1
        DC = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        DC.HeaderText = "Source: PKey" & (r + 1).ToString
        DC.ReadOnly = True
        DGV.Columns.Add(DC)
    Next
    For r = 0 To DTT.PrimaryKey.Length - 1
        DC = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        DC.HeaderText = "Target: PKey" & (r + 1).ToString
        DC.ReadOnly = True
        DGV.Columns.Add(DC)
    Next
    intNewRow = DGV.Rows.Add()
    DR = DGV.Rows(intNewRow)
    DR.HeaderCell.Value = "PKeys"
    For r = 0 To DTS.PrimaryKey.Length - 1
        DR.Cells(r).Value = DTS.PrimaryKey(r)
    Next
    intOffset = r
    For r = 0 To DTT.PrimaryKey.Length - 1
        DR.Cells(r + intOffset).Value = DTT.PrimaryKey(r)
    Next

End Sub

Private Function PrimarykeyCountMatches(DTS As DataTable, DTT As DataTable) As Boolean

    Return DTS.PrimaryKey.Length = DTT.PrimaryKey.Length

End Function

Private Function PrimarykeysMatch(DGV As DataGridView, DTS As DataTable, DTT As DataTable) As Boolean

    Dim DC As DataGridViewColumn
    Dim lisDiffSource As List(Of Integer)
    Dim lisDiffTarget As List(Of Integer)
    Dim DR As DataGridViewRow
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim bMatch As Boolean = False
    Dim intNewRow As Integer
    Dim PKeysSource As String()
    Dim PKeysTarget As String()
    Dim s As IOrderedEnumerable(Of DataColumn)
    Dim strSCaption As String
    Dim intSIndex As Integer
    Dim t As IOrderedEnumerable(Of DataColumn)
    Dim strTCaption As String
    Dim intTIndex As Integer

    s = DTS.PrimaryKey.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Caption)
    t = DTT.PrimaryKey.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Caption)


    lisDiffSource = New List(Of Integer)
    lisDiffTarget = New List(Of Integer)

    Do
        strSCaption = s(intSIndex).Caption.ToLower
        strTCaption = t(intTIndex).Caption.ToLower
        If strSCaption = strTCaption Then
            intSIndex += 1
            intTIndex += 1
        Else
            If strSCaption > strTCaption Then
                lisDiffTarget.Add(intTIndex)
                intTIndex += 1
            Else 'strSCaption < strTCaption
                lisDiffSource.Add(intSIndex)
                intSIndex += 1
            End If
        End If
    Loop While intSIndex < s.Count And intTIndex < t.Count


    While intSIndex < s.Count
        lisDiffSource.Add(intSIndex)
        intSIndex += 1
    End While

    While intTIndex < t.Count
        lisDiffTarget.Add(intTIndex)
        intTIndex += 1
    End While


    If lisDiffSource.Count = 0 And lisDiffTarget.Count = 0 Then
        bMatch = True
    Else

        DC = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        DC.HeaderText = "Table"
        DC.ReadOnly = True
        DGV.Columns.Add(DC)
        DC = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        DC.HeaderText = "Column"
        DC.ReadOnly = True
        DGV.Columns.Add(DC)
        DC = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        DC.HeaderText = "Status"
        DC.ReadOnly = True
        DGV.Columns.Add(DC)

        For Each intIndex In lisDiffSource
            intNewRow = DGV.Rows.Add()
            DR = DGV.Rows(intNewRow)
            DR.Cells(0).Value = "Source"
            DR.Cells(1).Value = s(intIndex).Caption
            DR.Cells(2).Value = "Missing from Target"
        Next

        For Each intIndex In lisDiffTarget
            intNewRow = DGV.Rows.Add()
            DR = DGV.Rows(intNewRow)
            DR.Cells(0).Value = "Target"
            DR.Cells(1).Value = t(intIndex).Caption
            DR.Cells(2).Value = "Missing from Source"
        Next

    End If

    Return bMatch

End Function

Private Function ColumnCountMatches(DTS As DataTable, DTT As DataTable) As Boolean

    Return DTS.Columns.Count = DTT.Columns.Count

End Function

Private Function ColumnsMatch(DTS As DataTable, DTT As DataTable) As Boolean

    Return True

End Function
```